# Git - Listing commits that are not promoted to parent

Tags: git, github

When I run the command: `git status` on my local git branch, I see the following:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/XXX' by 415 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)                   
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I am not sure how I got so many commits in my local branch when I did not do it. Is there a way for me to list all the commits + details associated with each commit so that I can understand what might have happened and if it safe for me to do a git push.

Comment: `git log` is the command that you're looking for I believe

Comment: FWIW, what probably happened is that you hadn't pulled in quite a while, then you made a commit, and then you pulled. The pull created a merge commit between all the commits you had "missed" (since you hadn't pulled for a while) and your commit. That is why you are seeing such a high number.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use Log and [specify a range](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges):

```
$ git log --oneline origin/XXX..HEAD
```

You can even omit `HEAD`:

```
$ git log --oneline origin/XXX..
```

Answer (score 1):

The below command will give you the list of files changed locally and not present in remote

```
git diff origin/XXX <local_branch> --name-only
```

If you want the entire diff then use

```
git diff origin/XXX <local_branch>
```